# How to create table and insert values in one statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been given the task to create a statement, which creates a table and then inserts values from a join of two different tables.

This is a hideous task, just to feed a small application with data, because it can't deal with views (and SQL server for that part)

Which brings me, to my CREATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE resultstable1_DIFF (
[Id] Counter Primary key not null,
[km] number,
[Diff] float)
```

And the INSERT Statement

```
Insert Into resultstable1_DIFF(km, Diff)
SELECT Round(A.km, 4), Round(X.y - A.y, 4)
FROM sourcetable_1_HQ100 as A INNER JOIN sourcetable_2 as X
ON Round(A.km, 4)  = Round(X.km, 4)
```

Unfortunatly UNION does not work here. Can somebody point me into the right direction? It is my goal, to create a loop for some 50-ish source table pairs.

If a VBA macro would result in a more elegant and reusable solution, it is fine by me.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Access supports [SELECT... INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx) so try to use:

```
SELECT Round(A.km, 4) as km, Round(X.y - A.y, 4)  as Diff
Into resultstable1_DIFF
FROM sourcetable_1_HQ100 as A INNER JOIN sourcetable_2 as X
ON Round(A.km, 4)  = Round(X.km, 4)
```

But here is the problem with the ID field. I guess you can't make a PK field this way:

> "You may want to define a primary key for the new table. When you
>   create the table, the fields in the new table inherit the data type
>   and field size of each field in the query's underlying tables, but no
>   other field or table properties are transferred."

Comment: The PK field is not neccessary and required by the applications logic. It is just a habit of mine to create one